# Is this a continuous function in $\ell_p$?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let $(x_n)_n$ a sequence in $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_ny_n $ converge for all $y=(y_n)_n\in\ell_p$, $p\ge 1$. Is $f:\ell_p\to \mathbb{K}$, where $f(y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_ny_n$, a continuous function?

Comment: Yes ... A nice application of the closed graph theorem.

Comment: Thank you!!!!  This is connected with another exercise I've already done.